# background image to cells table view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I have a little problem I would like to change the background image 
this the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // chemin de l'image
    NSString *img=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"title" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *ui=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:img];

    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text= [hadiths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    cell.imageView.image=ui;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return cell;

}
```

but the image appears and the text NO...

Answer (score 0):

`cell.imageView` is the icon (on the left) of the cell. The background is set using `cell. backgroundView`

Comment: thank even with cell.backgroundview the program gived me this error

**: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIImage *', expected 'struct UIView *' when passing argument 1 of 'setBackgroundView:' from distinct Objective-C type**

NSString *img=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cells" ofType:@"png"];
 UIImage *ui=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:img];
 
 UITableViewCell *cell=[[UI.TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
 **cell.backgroundView=ui;**

Comment: @walidiphone please move code in your comment to your question as additional information, this is unfortunately unreadable.

Comment: @walidiphone: It's crashing because you're using a UIImage as the backgroundView, which is not a UIView subclass. Use a UIImageView instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
NSString *img=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"title" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *ui=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:img]; 
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ui];
cell.backgroundView = imgView;
[imgView release];
```

OR

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"]] autorelease];
cell.backgroundView = imgView;
```

cell.backgroundView is subclass of UIView to which you are assigning UIImage which is obviously not a view so it gave you the error.

`[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"]` will load "title.png" image from the main bundle.

Comment: thanks a lot but the image dont cover all the cells juste the extremities i would like that cover all the cells and save the text

Comment: It seems that you want to apply background to your tableview. for that you can use backgroundView property of tableview, i.e. `UIImageView* imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"]] autorelease];
tableView.backgroundView = imgView;`. You also might want to nil out the background of cell so that the image applied is visible. for that you can do, ` cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; cell.backgroundView = nil;`